# Separate Strings from a .txt file to diferent textBoxes

Tags: c#

I need your help !
So, I have a `.txt` file with information of different users and I want to separate the different fields of each user to their respective textbox.
The lines of my `.txt` file are this:

```
1|João Pedro Almeida+Rua da Aliança,N55%joaoalmeida.pedro@hotmail.com&915435654!17/11/1997<987654328>

13|Pedro Costa Rica+Rua de Barcelos ,N47%pedrorica.barcelos@gmail.com&915632154!19/07/1987<237345828>

21|Henrique da Silva+Avenida dos Aliados,N9,Esquerdo%jairofonseca@hotmail.com&963215654!07/01/1993<3453245324>
```

The substrings are never separated from the way I want them.
For example, for the line "1|João Pedro Almeida+Rua da Aliança,N55%joaoalmeida.pedro@hotmail.com&915435654!17/11/1997<987654328>", the string should be separated accordingly to the following text boxes:

- textBoxId => "1";
- textBoxNome => "João Pedro Almeida";
- textBoxMorada => "Rua da Aliança,N55";
- textBoxEmail => "joaoalmeida.pedro@hotmail.com";
- textBoxContacto => "915435654";
- textBoxNasc => "17/11/1997";
- textBoxContr => "987654328";

The separators of the fields are: "|", "+", "%", "&", "!", "<", ">".
And my code is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Bd/clientes.txt");

  string item;
  int indexId;
  int indexNome;
  int indexMorada;
  int indexEmail;
  int indexContacto;
  int indexNasc;
  int indexContr;

  foreach (string textLine in text)
  {
    indexId = textLine.IndexOf('|');
    indexNome = textLine.IndexOf('+');
    indexMorada = textLine.IndexOf('%');
    indexEmail = textLine.IndexOf('&');
    indexContacto = textLine.IndexOf('!');
    indexNasc = textLine.IndexOf('<');
    indexContr = textLine.IndexOf('>');

    indexNome -= indexId;
    indexMorada -= indexNome;
    indexEmail -= indexMorada;

    if (indexId > 0)
    {
        item = textLine.Substring(0, indexId);
        textBoxId.Text = item;
    }
    if (indexNome > 0)
    {
        indexId = textLine.IndexOf('|');
        item = textLine.Substring(indexId + 1, indexNome - 1);
        textBoxNome.Text = item;
    }
    if (indexMorada > 0)
    {
        indexNome = textLine.IndexOf('+');
        indexMorada -= (indexId);
        item = textLine.Substring(indexNome + 1, indexMorada - 1);
        textBoxMorada.Text = item;
    }
    if (indexEmail > 0)
    {
        indexMorada = textLine.IndexOf('%');
        indexEmail -= (indexNome + indexId);
        item = textLine.Substring(indexMorada + 1, indexEmail + 1);
        textBoxEmail.Text = item;
    }
    if (indexContacto > 0)
    {
        indexEmail = textLine.IndexOf('&');
        indexContacto -= (indexNome + indexId + indexMorada);
        item = textLine.Substring(indexEmail + 1, indexContacto + 1);
        textBoxContacto.Text = item;
    }
    if (indexNasc > 0)
    {
        indexContacto = textLine.IndexOf('!');
        indexNasc -= (indexNome + indexId + indexMorada + indexEmail);
        //item = textLine.Substring(indexContacto + 1, indexNasc + 1);
        //textBoxNasc.Text = item;
    }

    if (indexContr > 0)
    {
        indexNasc = textLine.IndexOf('<');
        indexContr -= (indexNome + indexId + indexMorada + indexContacto + indexEmail);
        //item = textLine.Substring(indexNasc + 1, indexContr);
        //textBoxContribuinte.Text = item;
    }
  }
}
```

I would appreciate the help, and thank you! 
Ps.: Sorry for my english...

Comment: This would be a great candidate for [Regular Expressions](https://regexone.com/references/csharp).

Comment: "but I keep getting some mis caracteres in some textboxes".  please elaborate on this so we understand the issue

Comment: simply step through the code with the VS debugger and watch what happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to get all parts of the `'text'` lines would be to use '`String.Split`' method.

Use it like this:

```
foreach (string textLine in text)
  {
      string[] parts = textLine.Split(new char[] {'|', '+', '%', '&', '!', '<', '>' });
      // Now you have all the parts of the line in the `'parts'` `String Array`.
      // They can be accessed by index.
  }
```